# Copy text from one tmux pane to another (using vim)

Tags: vim, tmux, copy-paste

I have two files opened in vim, each in one tmux pane. I would like to copy let's say 10 lines from one file to another.

How can I accomplish this not using the mouse's `Copy` -> `Paste` ?

Comment: You could involve *tmux*, but there are generally simpler ways. Are both the Vim instances on the same (local?) machine? Usually, I would just use a temporary file for that (i.e. visually select the lines, `:w /tmp/lines`, then `:r /tmp/lines` in the other instance). Or, if your Vim knows how to talk to your system clipboard, you could use the `+` or `*` registers to avoid the temporary file.

Comment: `tmux`'s ["copy mode" commands and default keyboard shortcuts](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#WINDOWS_AND_PANES) in the man page for reference.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

You'll have to use tmux shortcuts. Assuming your tmux command shortcut is the default: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, then:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd> Enter copy(?) mode.
2. Move to start/end of text to highlight.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Start highlighting text (on Arch Linux). When I've compiled tmux from source on OSX and other Linux's, just <kbd>Space</kbd> on its own usually works. Selected text changes the colours, so you'll know if the command worked.

4. Move to opposite end of text to copy.
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> Copies selected text into `tmux` clipboard.
   On Mac, use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. Try <kbd>Enter</kbd> if none of the above work.
6. Move cursor to opposite tmux pane, or completely different tmux window. Put the cursor where you want to paste the text you just copied.
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd> Paste copied text from tmux clipboard.

`tmux` is quite good at mapping commands to custom keyboard shortcuts.

See <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>?</kbd> for the full list of set keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks. Just a sidenode: The Alt + w did not work on Mac. Alt was mapped to Esc by default. Hence it is Esc+w.

Comment: @KaranThis is not true for me on OS X 10.10.5 with tmux 2.0, although alt+w doesn't copy the text either.

Comment: if you use `screen` shortcuts: `Ctrl + A [` (enter copy-mode), `Space` (start highlighting), `Enter` (end highlighting), `Ctrl + A ]` (paste).

Comment: Accessing tmux on ubuntu 16.04LTS, using putty as terminal on Windows 10. All the commands that @alexleach mentioned worked great

Comment: "y" also works and also copies to system clipboard as well which is what I prefer.

Comment: Worth noting that "enter" works for me whereas alt+w does not.

Comment: As noted in https://awhan.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/copy-paste-in-tmux/, if you have vi key bindings, step 5 should be replaced with `Enter` key.

Comment: what If I need to copy and paste to a text editor? For some reason it doesn't seem to pick up that selected text even after pressing 'enter' after selecting the text.

Comment: Note if you have in your `.tmux.conf` the lines `set -g mode-keys vi` and `set -g status-keys vi`, you can move with VI movement commands, enter selection mode with `v`/`V`, and copy the text with `y`.

Comment: you just saved my day :)

Comment: @alex-leach please consider adjusting step 5 for mac to copy to the clipboard using `Enter`

Comment: but how do I paste it out of tmux like to an email? it seems your answer only works if I want to stay within tmux

Comment: For me it (system clipboard) only worked  when I replaced step 5 with `Ctrl+b`, `y` to yank/copy.

Comment: none of these copy commands are working

Comment: For me below worked on tmux 1.8 running on Putty 0.73 on Windows. COPY: ctrl+b,] got to start line, press Spacebar (it wills tart selection), use arrow or PageUp to go to end line, press Enter. PASTE: ctrl+b,]

Answer (score 50):

Unfortunately, I can't add a comment yet to Alex Leach's answer so I'm going to include an addendum here for Mac OS X users:

5. <kbd>Enter</kbd> Copies the selected text

Comment: thanks! I am on Ubuntu Xenial, using `byobu`/`tmux` with all default settings, this worked, Alt + w did not.

Comment: This doesn't work on OS X Yosemite with tmux 2.0, nor does alt+w, nor does esc+w :(

Comment: Works for me too on Windows using a Zoc terminal.

Comment: why doesn't command+c work?

Answer (score 25):

If you are using vim and tmux on macOS (Tested on macOS 10.12.2, tmux 2.3):

(Assume that prefix key combination of tmux is <kbd>prefix</kbd>. The prefix is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> in defaults.)

- Copy:

  1. Press <kbd>prefix</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to enter copy mode.
  2. Use arrow keys to go to the start/end of text selection.
  3. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> (If you have set <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> as prefix, Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> instead)
  4. Use arrow keys to move to the other side of selection.
  5. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>.
- Paste:

  1. Press <kbd>prefix</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> in insert mode.

Comment: I am on mac os and in step 3, pressing only `space` works, in step 5, pressing `return` works.

Comment: but how do I paste it out of tmux like to an email?

Comment: I'm on macOS Big Sur with tmux from brew. In step 5, `return` does not work, but I can confirm that `ctrl-W` does.

Answer (score 20):

I am connecting to my CentOS server on a Windows machine using [ZOC terminal](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/) ssh client. Here is what works for me:

- Enter copy mode: `<prefix>`+`[`
- Start copy: `<Space>`
- Copy text: `<Enter>`
- Paste text: `<prefix>`+`]`

Comment: but how do I paste it out of tmux like to an email?

Answer (score 8):

If you have `vim` open, its better to use the vim copy paste to copy text.

Tmux copy paste will work, however there are several disadvantages.

First, when copying multiple lines of text, you will have to select multiple lines. Tmux copy paste typically doesnt understand that `vim` has line numbers or there are markings in the vim gutter (such as relative numbers/absolute numbers). As a result, it will copy those as well.

Secondly, I have found that if the text has certain language specific formatting, and you directly try to copy paste using tmux to vim, it will mess up the formatting. This can be avoided by using `set paste!`. However, this requires a lot more work.

#### Use `"+y` to copy and `"+p` to paste

`Vim` natively provides a method to copy paste between the vim buffer and the system clipboard, using either `"+y` or `"*y`. Then pasting using `"+p` or `"*p`. This will avoide copying the relative numbers in the gutter or other random marks which are not relevant to vim

Comment: I don't get it. I tried copying in vim with "+y, but when switching to a pane that has a normal shell, trying to paste with "+p wont work, because it will start typing "...etc What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SFbay007 in case you were still wondering or someone else stumbles upon this, the "+y [y]anks (copies) the text into the clipboard (+) register ("). If you are [p]asting in vim, you use "+p, but if you are pasting in a normal shell you would use your normal method of paste (eg ctrl + shift + v). Note you may need to use the * register instead, depending on your system

Answer (score 4):

You could use the system clip board with "*y and "*p instead of the normal y and p.

Comment: To use system clipboard you have to use `"+2yy` – copy two lines to X11 clipboard
`"+dd` – cut line to X11 clipboard
`"+p` – paste X11 clipboard

Comment: Do I need to type anything before using these commands?

Comment: @ThomasAhle, no.. its literally the double quotes ("), followed by plus (+) followed by 2ys (y). Make sure you are in normal mode. If you are in normal mode, you should be able to use `h,j,k,l` to move . I have also seen sometimes on my ubuntu VM, the "+" register vanishes, for unknown reason. To verify that you have the `+` register, you can type `:reg` and check whether there is string `"+` in the first column.

Comment: Yes, this is it, this is the answer. Much simpler than the other ones suggested (using tmux copy/paste) and this doesn't mess line numbers. Would this cause any issues if you remapped standard `y` and `p` to `"+y` and `"+p` ?

Answer (score 2):

I have chosen to use `Ctrl+Alt+C` and `Ctrl+Alt+V` to copy and paste within tmux. Tmux's `copy-mode-vi` enables navigation within a tmux pane with vim keys `hjkl^$...`, rectangle mode is useful to copy table columns or when there are further splits within the pane, activate it with `r`.

Here is how I set it up in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind P paste-buffer
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi r send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
# Also copy to system clipboard
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -sel clip -i'
# map copy mode to ctrl+alt+c
bind-key -n 'C-M-c' copy-mode
# map paste buffer to ctrl+alt+v
bind-key -n 'C-M-v' paste-buffer
```

I created this setup by modifying this [blog post](https://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/).

This copy-paste solution will also work if the 2 tmux panes (vim instances or anything else) are on different machines (one remote, one local).

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options for vim use since the tmux shortcut sequence is bit long and I find it hard to remember

Like the answers above said you can use `"+y` and `"*y` to copy and then `"+p` and `"*p` respectively to paste. If you want vim to use the clipboard by default so you can just use `y/p` directly then.

```
set clipboard=unamed "sets the default copy register to be *
set clipboard=unamedplus "sets the default copy register to be +
```

source for clipboard command: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim

Answer (score 0):

I've had the issue myself and uploaded my .vimrc and .tmux.conf files here:
[tvp-repl](https://github.com/DarioHett/tvp-repl)

You can configure tmux to

1. Copy the vim-pane selection to the clipboard,
2. Read the clipboard and paste it to another pane, and
3. Jump back to the original pane.

All you need to set up vim to copy to clipboard [visual mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>]:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
vnoremap <C-c> "+y
```

Then have tmux command to run copying from vim and pasting the buffer to another pane [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> Enter]:

```
bind-key Enter run "tmux send-keys -t 0 C-c" \; 
run "tmux select-pane -t 1" \; 
run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)\"; tmux paste-buffer" \; 
run "tmux send-keys -t 1 Enter" \; 
run "tmux select-pane -t 0"
```

Notice:
a) This script requires **xclip** to interface with the clipboard.
b) Assumption is vim is in pane 0; target pane is pane 1.