# Is it possible to share the tmux buffer across sessions?

Tags: tmux

I typically have 2-3 tmux sessions running on my server, and almost always have 2 up at a time, 1 on each monitor.  Occasionally I want to take something I copied from one session and paste it into the other session.

Most of the time I can use the system clipboard to get around that, but that usually involves using my mouse, and I'd like to avoid that.  Also for larger chunks it can be hard to get into the system clipboard.

Is there a way to link the buffers together?  I guess alternatively I'd live with always having the copy put it in the system clipboard.

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233604/3217076
http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58765/115112

Comment: Nope... that's all within 1 tmux instance, and it's what I do now when copying between panes and tabs.  

I have two terminal windows open, each running a separate tmux session.  So when I do the copy in one, I'd like it if I could get that paste buffer in the other tmux process.