# Fedora 23, how avoid ctrl+shift layout switch with another ctrl+shift hotkeys?

Tags: fedora, kde, keyboard-layout

If I try to select words in a text editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>, or try to copy text from a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, it doesn't work. How can I fix this? I use KDE.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with openSUSE 43.2 Leap and GNOME 3

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why it should work in console, since console is not a text editor. In console, you have different priorities.

But if you really want to select text in the console using keyboard, it is possible to do so in `tmux`, which is described in this [related questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58763/copy-text-from-one-tmux-pane-to-another-using-vim).

Comment: No, i can't select text by worlds even in text editor.

Comment: it is unclear what you are aksing. What text editor?

Comment: Any text editor, any text input field in any application or input on any web page. Any hotkey begining from ctrl+shift+.... doesnt't work when changing layout by ctrl+shift selected.