# System wide vim paste buffer in runlevel 3

Tags: linux, vim

I am a little embarrassed to ask this question, but this topic seems to be particularly difficult to search.

On Linux systems I almost exclusively use the terminal and access the systems (from macOS most often) using SSH through a terminal emulator.

In the general sense, copying and pasting code snippets and errors from logs, etc. is a tricky problem to traverse the buffer across systems, when a terminal multiplexer is involved, and this is usually achieved by copying via the terminal emulator's own selection feature and use the client's OS's paste buffer. This question is NOT ABOUT THAT.

My issue is when I have a large number of vim instances open on a single Linux server. I am in runlevel 3 and do not run a GUI. There is no xclip available to me, mainly because X is not installed.

When I am in this workflow I find the need to yank parts of files and paste them in other vims on the same remove box. Vim's builtin `+` and `*` copy/paste buffers do not work. (the clipboard compile option in vim is not enabled on these systems)

However, what works is if I yank some text in one vim instance, quit it, and open another vim instance, then pasting works. So something about exiting vim persists the buffer somewhere. I think that if I can just have whatever this system is work in realtime without having to close vims, that would be great. I would like to avoid having to layer a bind on yanks and deletes to implement my own yank/paste implementation.

Comment: In the long term, consider using `tmux` /`screen` and their internal clipboard: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58765/70524. Running `tmux` or `screen` will be handy if you spend a lot of time on SSH.

Comment: I have been using tmux HEAVILY for the last 5 years. The problem with the copy mode, which I also use often, is that when you have some content open in Vim and want to yank it out, you’ll get line numbers and other stuff. Sure I can toggle them off (my fancy Vim paste mode bind turns off line numbers) but it’s all just a few steps more than strictly necessary, mainly due to the extra overhead of tmux copy-mode’s own cursor selection navigation layer that now involves. I actually just implemented my macOS and Linux terminal pastebuffer final solution today, and it is very elegant and effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the `.viminfo` file ([`:h viminfo`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#viminfo)).

When you exit vim it writes out the current state, such as command history and register values to that file. When it starts, it reads the file and restores whatever state it describes. That means that *successive* vim sessions (appear to) share some state, but concurrent ones don't.

You can forcibly re-read the viminfo file with the [`:rv`/`:rviminfo` command](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#%3Arviminfo), and manually write it out with [`:wv`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#%3Awviminfo). So <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>:wv</kbd> in one editor, and <kbd>:rv</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> in the other will work, but there will be side effects: *all* your register values and command history may be reset, and quite a lot of other things, which may or may not matter to you.

That can also be an advantage: you can use the full range of registers to get multiple copy buffers between editors, which the system clipboard doesn't provide. On the other hand, it's not terribly convenient unless you rebind `y` to do this automatically, and `p` you probably don't want to read the file every time. I have read/write viminfo bound to leader commands, but that only saves me one keypress (and it sounds like you'd use it more often).

---

There are some other approaches you could use, like paging out manually [to a specific file](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#writefile%28%29) yourself, which would avoid the side effects. It doesn't sound like you want that, but it's an option. There are also plugins that do more or less of what you're looking for, and the sessions system as well. They aren't direct answers to your question but they may inform where you want to end up.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for explaining everything!

Comment: Do you think you could comment on how practical it would be to implement something that uses temp files in `/tmp` maybe, as scripts or aliases named `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` for use in a Linux under these conditions (without X)? It seems straightforward. I guess the best thing for me to do now is to just try it.

Comment: It seems fairly trivial, though you might need some caution about security of the files. Just reading and writing a well-known location should be good enough.

Comment: Indeed this does work. I just have a simple bash script now named `pbcopy_linux` that saves stdin to a file in my home directory which it also runs `chmod 600` on. Now I can also implement a set of bindings in Vim for yanking into and pasting out of this file, and it will work with these (trivial) pbcopy/pbpaste programs. Very very simple.

Comment: You can post your own answer to this question describing how you do that if you like, so other people wanting the same thing can use it too.

Comment: Yeah I think I will do that but not before using and testing the solution for a few days. And it really has some vim integration components to it, the copy/paste programs are really just too trivial for an answer.

Comment: I have now written my answer and am using it, but I dont really want to take away your accept. Your answer addresses my question, anyway, so it is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

As promised:

The linux specific scripting (my `$HOME/util` is in my `$PATH`):

```
~/util ❯❯❯ cat linux_pb/pbcopy                                         ✘ 130 master b28083b $ ◼
#!/bin/bash

# pbcopy impl for linux!
# pipe the stdin to a file using cat. Not using bash builtins due to concerns
# about NULs.

FILE="$HOME/.clipboard"
touch $FILE
chmod 600 $FILE
cat > $FILE
~/util ❯❯❯ cat linux_pb/pbpaste                                              master b28083b $ ◼
#!/bin/bash

# pbpaste impl for linux!
# just use the content of the file.

cat ~/.clipboard
```

The vim bindings:

```
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>y :w !pbcopy<CR><CR>
" the leader y works like normal yy (but for my clipboard)
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>y :.w !pbcopy<CR><CR>
nnoremap <Leader>p :read !pbpaste<CR>
```

The idempotent shell alias script (I source this alias script from bash and zsh):

```
if [ "$(uname)" = Linux ] && ! [[ "$PATH" = *"/linux_pb"* ]]; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/util/linux_pb"
fi
```

I will likely flesh out the Linux configuration even more when I start to use an actual linux with X, so that I may also take advantage of its paste buffer also. It would require some mechanism to create `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` programs similar to [this](https://superuser.com/a/288333).

The approach is one of uniformity at the program level, so Vim can leverage the functionality exactly like I am now able to from the shell.